# list returned from recursive function always empty

Tags: python, pymel

Im trying to return a list from a recursive function, appending to this list for each depth, but the final returned list is always empty.
I'm not very experienced pythonian so it might be a trivial mistake.

Here's the code:

```
import pymel.core as pm

def getParent(jnt):
    something = pm.listRelatives(jnt, parent=True);
    if something:
        print 'got parent: ' + something[0]
        return something[0]
    else:
        return None

def getAllParents(jnt):
    parents = []
    parents.append(jnt)
    prnt = getParent(jnt)
    if prnt == None:
        return parents
    else:
        prnts = parents.insert(0, getAllParents(prnt))
        return prnts


selection = pm.ls(sl=True)[0]

parents = getAllParents(selection)

print '\n'
print parents
```

`pm.listRelatives(jnt, parent=True);` returns a list of strings, of which i grab the first if it is not empty.

Here's the output:

```
got parent: joint3
got parent: joint2
got parent: joint1


None
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try placing your parents list outside the function

Comment: `parents[] = []`??? is the right syntax??

Comment: @Tanmayjain no difference.
no, `parents[] = []` is incorrect, typo. (it's not the issue)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `prnts = parents.insert(0, getAllParents(prnt))`

Comment: `parents [] = []` is an issue. This code does not return an empty list, because it has a syntax error. So what does your code actually look like? Please fix the question.

Comment: please, see the comment from @MarcinOrlowski. is it a typo or not ?

Comment: it is a typo. Question has been edited

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
def getAllParents(jnt):
    # ...
    prnts = parents.insert(0, getAllParents(prnt))
    return prnts
```

`list.insert()` (as well as all methods that modify a list in place - `sort()` etc) returns `None`. You want:

```
    parents.insert(0, getAllParents(prnt))
    return parents
```

instead.

Comment: This was indeed the issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAllParents` method takes a string and returns a list. Then you insert this list into another list which makes it a list of strings and lists of strings and lists...

To concatenate two lists you can simply use `+` operator, so:

```
prnts = getAllParents(prnt) + parents
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you're using list functions like `append`, `insert` passing list. In this case you'll end-up to weird results.
For instance

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
print(a.append(b))

>> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but I guess the following code works fine

```
listPrts = ["","toto","idiot","happy"]

def getParent(jnt):
    something = listPrts
    del listPrts[0]
    if something:
        print 'got parent: ' + something[0]
        return something[0]
    else:
        return None

def getAllParents(jnt):
    parents = []
    parents.append(jnt)
    prnt = getParent(jnt)
        if prnt == None:
            return parents
        else:
            prnts = parents.insert(0, getAllParents(prnt))
            return parents


selection = "childof"

parents = getAllParents(selection)

print '\n'
print parents
```